# Android emulator compatibility with Google APIs

Tags: android, emulation

I wrote a simple code which implements MapView using Eclipse and ADT plug-in updated today. in order to test it I created a new emulator based on Galaxy Nexus device and target for Google APIs level 17. The emulator has been created without errors and starts properly.

I set project properties for targeting Google APIs. I compiled the project and I tried to run in on my emulator, but I got a warning message: No compatible targets were found, Do you wish to add a new Android Virtual Device?

Independently on the button I click, a new avd windows appear and my new emulator is highlighted by a red cross instead of the green check sign.

I can choose to ignore the warning and continue with my emulator, but my application blocks before reaching main activity onCreate() method I am sure because I have placed a breakpoint inside the method which is never reached.

I added internet permission tag to manifest ans API keycode I got from Google.

Is anyone able to explain me what is the problem with my project?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you used Google APIs level 17 as the target of your project, make sure your **emulator's API level** is also **17**.
You could have possibly created an emulator using Google API but the API level is different.

To check the emulator's API level, open your AVD, then confirm if target name is Google APIs(Google Inc.) and API level is 17.